# Navigating from one lightning record page to another record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to achieve the below requirement in lightning. Whenever we are changing the sales stage of an opportunity a visualforce page is getting redirected where it asks you if you want to create a meeting event or not. Upon creation the same you need to redirect again back to Opportunity. How to achieve the same in lightning.

I was trying to create an application event where I can set the OpportunityId in an attribute through a Lightning component which is there in the opportunity lightning record page. And when the event record is created, the listener component in the event record pages trying to get the event parameter value and fires the e.force:navigateTosObject compoenent with the opportunityId. But this working in a very weird manner. PFB the code.

Registering the event in LC of opportunity

```
<aura:registerevent name="RedirectToOppty" type="c:NavigateToOpportunity"/>
```

Controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:NavigateToOpportunity");
        evt.setParams({ "opportunityId": component.get("v.OpptyId")});
        evt.fire();
```

Application event:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" >
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityId" type="Id"/>
</aura:event>
```

LC in event object:

```
<aura:attribute name="OpportunityId" type="Id"/>
<aura:handler event="c:NavigateToOpportunity" action="{!c.navToOpportunity}"/> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

Controller:

```
navToOpportunity : function(component, event, helper) {
    var eventvalues = event.getParam("opportunityId");
    console.log('@@OpptyId@@'+eventvalues);
    component.set("v.OpportunityId",eventvalues);     
    },
doInit:function(component, event, helper)
{
    var optyId = component.get("v.OpportunityId");
    console.log('@@valeu recieved from attribute@@'+component.get("v.OpportunityId"));

    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    alert('Init function!!!');
    alert('From Init function'+optyId);
    if(optyId){
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": optyId,
      "slideDevName": "detail"
    });
        navEvt.fire();
    }
}
```

The problem here is, optyId in above controller does not get any value and set to null. Could you please let me know if application eventcan be used here or not. Since the container app is getting changed in this context , will the application event works. If not then please let know the work around of the same.

Answer (score 0):

`init` always occurs first, thus your `NavigateToOpportunity` method won't be called until later. Instead, put your `force:navigateToSObject` in the `navToOpportunity` function.

Comment: I tried putting 'force:navigateToSObject' inside navToOpportunity function but did not work. but in the console i can see the value has been set.

Comment: @SomnathPaul Are you in the correct context? You must be in LEX, Salesforce app, or a Community for it to work. You may be trying to do the wrong thing.

Comment: Sorry I mean to say in console.log i can see the value of opportunity id. But navigatetoSobject doesnot work.

Comment: @SomnathPaul Yes, but are you using it in the right environment? You can't use it in Visualforce, for example.

Comment: I am using it in the lightning component controller.

Comment: Just wanted to check if my understanding is correct. You have a lightning component (say "A") embedded in "Opportunity Lighting Record" page, which handles the oppty stage changes. Then you have another lightning component (say "B") which handles "meeting event" creation.  You are redirecting user from "A" to "B" and once user is done with "meeting event" creation, you want to redirect user back to original Oppty. Once you confirm this understanding is correct, we can help you with how to design it.

Comment: Yes Mandy that is absolutely correct understanding.

Comment: @MandyKool You are correct. Your understanding is correct.